# Burninate [altium-designer] Discussion

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've just noticed a tag for an electronics design tool: [altium-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altium-designer). I think it's off-topic and perhaps should be migrated to the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Note: It seems that this tool is scriptable, in DelphiScript, but we already have a tag for that.

There are 26 questions, 14 unanswered. Only 3 have upvotes. 1 question this year, 6 last year.

I looked at all the questions, and I'd say that maybe 2 seem on-topic for SO, the rest are either off-topic or way off-topic. A lot of the questions have screenshots, most of the questions are about how to use the app, and a couple are about electronics. The overall quality of the posts are low.

The only question with a half-decent number of upvotes, 17, is about using the tool with Git, the answer for which is that you can't: [How to use Altium with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121233/how-to-use-altium-with-git)

Should this tag be removed?

Comment: Note that questions older than 60 days cannot even be migrated by mods, just close them instead if they're off-topic. (Also, [the tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27228415/revisions) is confusing).

Comment: The only thing that is on-topic would be the scripting in that tool. Questions about how to use the tool is off-topic. It could be on-topic elsewhere. The wiki/excerpt needs an update as a start.

Comment: This can probably be handled without a formal burn process, there are only 27 questions. At the moment, [15 have only the single tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1399339/find-questions-with-only-the-given-tag?tagname=altium-designer). There's also little to no agreement on what tags to use in conjunction with this one either: [22 out of the 24 unique tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=altium-designer) used with this one are on only a single question in this tag.

Comment: I just spent time going through each question and flagging for off topic if necessary, and darn near every single question falls into the "not about programming" category. This tag needs to go.